# Getting ANDROID_ID Trying to understand the java

Tags: java, android

I'm still new to programming/Java/Android so I'm trying to understand everything I do and trying to figure out how to properly read the reference section of developer.android.com and so maybe one of you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance

These calls get me the ANDROID_ID. They both give me the same output. I just do not understand how the Second Way works. It shouldn't work in my opinion.

### First way

```
AndroidID = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

### Second way

```
AndroidID = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Why does it work like that?

I used [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) to find the getString() method. I get the ANDROID_ID. It works perfectly using both calls, but I want to know why it works the second way.

Comment: It would help if you included a link to the section of the page on developer.android.com where those two lines of code came from.

Comment: What is the difference between these things? Is Secure a different object from Settings.Secure? Have you checked your imports? If you've imported Settings.Secure at the top, Secure is likely just resolving to Settings.Secure.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Paul. That's the answer. Settings.Secure was being imported but Secure is "resolving" it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason is because you have:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
```

In your imports. Similarly you'll find that both DialogInterface and View have different implementations of classes called OnClickListener, but you can still do something like:

```
// View.OnClickLitener
OnClickListener foo = new OnClickListener(...) {
     ...
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener bar = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(...) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: And that's called "resolving" or is there another technical term for how it knows that by saying "Secure" I really mean "Settings.Secure"

Comment: I don't know a lot about technical terms, but I think that resolving something to a type is taking some input that has the form of a static reference to a class (whether it's in the type declaration or using a static method), and figuring out which class that's supposed to be. I know nothing about Java's history, but I imagine that the whole package namespace conventions are supposed to be analogous to DNS, where named addresses have to be resolved to IP addresses.

In python, I think it's even more like that, where you can do things like "import os.path as opath".

Comment: So, sorry, yes, I would say that what's happening there is Secure is resolved to android.provider.Settings.Secure, which presumably eventually resolves to some physical address in memory on your machine.